# Customize Json Output with Jersey and Jaxb

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey

I am trying to create a simple web service which outputs using json, but am not getting the desired Json output.

POJO:
    package com.rest.resource;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Track implements Serializable
       {

       @XmlElement
       String   singer   = "ABC";
       @XmlElement
       String   title    = "XYZ";
       }
```

Service:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import com.rest.resource.Track;

@Path("/json/metallica")
public class JSONService
   {

   @POST
   @Path("/post")
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public Track createTrackInJSON(final Track track)
      {
       return track;
      }

   @GET
   @Path("/get")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public Response getTrackInJSON() throws JAXBException
      {
      final Track track = new Track();
      return Response.status(201).entity(track).build();
      }

   }
```

On /get I get

{"singer":"ABC","title":"XYZ"}

but I want "track": {"singer":"ABC","title":"XYZ"}
I am unable yo print the root element.

I tried using a CustomJAXBContextResolver class but did not work for me? Can anyone give an example of the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the `ContextResolver`, you'd need to use the `JSONConfiguration` and switch the JSON Notation. You could do that by adding a class like this:

```
@Provider
public class MyJAXBContextProvider implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

    private JSONJAXBContext trackCtx;

    public MyJAXBContextProvider() throws JAXBException {
        trackCtx = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.mappedJettison().build(), Track.class);
    }

    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> type) {
        if(type == Track.class) {
            return trackCtx;
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Adding that class produced this for me:

`{"track":{"singer":"ABC","title":"XYZ"}}`

For more info check out the Jersey [Docs](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/json.html#json.jaxb.context.resolver.example)

Comment: Hey this works very well for get requests but post requests fail.
Would you have any idea why or something that I should tweak?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to wrap `Track` with another object:

```
public class TrackWrapper {
  Track track;
  TrackWrapper(Track track) {
    this.track=track;
  }
}
```

and return an instance of `TrackWrapper`,

```
@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getTrackInJSON() throws JAXBException
  {
  final TrackWrapper trackWrapper = new TrackWrapper(new Track());
  return Response.status(201).entity(trackWrapper).build();
  }

}
```

and just in case, if you're gonna use JSON only you don't need the JAXB annotations.

Comment: That's a good solution and thanks for answering but is there anything else I can do?
I was reading something about - CustomJaxbContexResolver etc. but could not make it work for me.
You solution does solve the problem though.

Comment: Hey which annotations should I use

Comment: jersey uses jackson as JSON processing library by default, here's the reference for jackson: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/

Comment: however, the default jackson configuration (with no annotations) is enough for most use cases, try without annotations and use them only if you have to